# How to tune the margin in victory?

Tags: css, reactjs, d3.js, svg, victory-charts

Below is a general victory code.

```
 <svg viewBox={viewBox}>
          <VictoryPie
            standalone={false}
            width={width} height={height}
            data={data}
            innerRadius={innerRadius}
            colorScale={colorScale}

          />
          <VictoryLegend x={width - 50} y={30}
            title="Totals"
            centerTitle
            orientation="vertical"
            gutter={20}
            style={{
              title: { fontSize: 15 }
            }}
            data={legendDataWithStyle}
            standalone={false}
          />
</svg>
```

This is the corresponding [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuhang1128/z7x34s2y/2/)

I was using `VictoryLegend x={width - 50} y={30}` to regulate the distance of piechart and legend. But I found it's hard to precisely tune it. How can I increase the distance of the pie and legend?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you use [`g`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) element with the appropriate value for `transform` attribute

> The **g** SVG element is a container used to group other SVG elements.
>   Transformations applied to the  element are performed on all of its
>   child elements, and any of its attributes are inherited by its child
>   elements.

And `width` and `height` attributes for `svg` element instead of `viewBox`.
I forked your fiddle, check please - https://jsfiddle.net/levsha/5tx2s8jj/
here [the diff between your and my code](https://www.diffchecker.com/BhIj97Ah).

```
<svg width={width + 100} height={height}> // we add 100 here to legend fits in svg
```

...

```
<g transform="translate(40,0)"> // we move legend on 40px here
  <VictoryLegend x={width} y={30}
    title="Totals"
    centerTitle
    orientation="vertical"
    gutter={20}
    style={{
     title: { fontSize: 15 }
    }}
    data={legendDataWithStyle}
    standalone={false}
  />
</g>
```

Comment: @liamxu I'm glad to help.